# 3 Array ForEach Loop SQL Query

Tags: powershell

I have a SQL Server, SQL Database, and Company array that I need to run a forEach Loop on.

I can do it with a single value array but I have NO idea how to do it for multiple arrays needing the information from the other arrays

Each position in the array corresponds to information about the others.  i.e. Company1 uses DB01 with database AR_Agency1, Company2 uses DB02 and database AR_Agency2(See array below).

Ex:

```
$Company = (“Company1″,”Company2″,”Company3″,”Company4″,”Company5”)
$DatabaseServer = (“DB01”, “DB02”, “DB03”, “DB04”, “DB02”)
$Database= (“AR_Agency1”, “AR_Agency2”, “Agency3”, “Agency4”, “Agency5”)
#SQL Query
$Query = ‘UPDATE tblAsyncJobQueue SET InactiveUntil = NULL’
```

So what I want to do is something like this

```
ForEach ($company in $companies) {
#Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $DatabasesServer -Database $Database -Query $Query

}
```

End state I need the query run on each Company database.

Comment: When you crosspost the same question at the same time to different forums you should at least post links to the other forums along with your question to avoid people willing to you help making their work twice or more.Thanks  [https://powershell.org/forums/topic/3-array-powershell-foreach-loop/](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/3-array-powershell-foreach-loop/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already answered at Powershell.org, a hash table might work. For simple workloads, it's easier to use indexed loops instead of foreach.

Since all the releated info for a company, server and database are at the same location, accessing nth company means nth server and nth database too. Array elements are accessed via `[]` notation like so,

```
for($i=0; $i -lt $Company.Length; ++$i) {
  write-host $("Process {0} / {1} / {2}" -f $company[$i], $databaseserver[$i], $database[$i])
}

# Output
Process Company1 / DB01 / AR_Agency1
Process Company2 / DB02 / AR_Agency2
Process Company3 / DB03 / Agency3
Process Company4 / DB04 / Agency4
Process Company5 / DB02 / Agency5
```